# Is brute force the only way to make an update query in access?

Tags: database

I am trying to make an update query in Access right now. I have two teachers who have the same  data tables in a different database except for the information that they have entered in themselves. Other than their individually entered info, everything is the same. I am trying to merge their two tblDemographics tables so that they can see what each other has done in case a students moves to one of the schools they cover.  I was wondering if I have to basically enter in every field that has to be updated to, or is there some short hand that might make it to where I can basically say where Null, update to field of same name?

Sorry if this doesn't make sense. I just am trying to see if there is a more efficient way to do it.

```
UPDATE tbleDemographics LEFT JOIN tbleDemographics1 ON tbleDemographics.[Local ID] = tbleDemographics1.[Local ID] SET tbleDemographics.FName = [tbleDemographics1.Fname], tbleDemographics.LName = [tbleDemographics1.LName], tbleDemographics.MName = [tbleDemographics1.MName]
WHERE (((tbleDemographics.FName) Is Null) AND ((tbleDemographics.LName) Is Null) AND ((tbleDemographics.MName) Is Null) AND ((tbleDemographics.ClMgr) Is Null) AND ((tbleDemographics.School) Is Null) AND ((tbleDemographics.Grade) Is Null) AND ((tbleDemographics.[Prim Dis]) Is Null) AND ((tbleDemographics.[Sec Dis]) Is Null) AND ((tbleDemographics.[Third Dis]) Is Null) AND ((tbleDemographics.[Local ID]) Is Null) AND ((tbleDemographics.GTID) Is Null) AND ((tbleDemographics.Status) Is Null) AND ((tbleDemographics.[Homeroom Teacher]) Is Null) AND ((tbleDemographics.[GPS Math Teacher]) Is Null) AND ((tbleDemographics.[Number Worlds Teacher]) Is Null) AND ((tbleDemographics.IntervHMcCain) Is Null) AND ((tbleDemographics.InterMSmith) Is Null) AND ((tbleDemographics.InterALacey) Is Null) AND ((tbleDemographics.InterLDaughtry) Is Null) AND ((tbleDemographics.DelInclusion) Is Null) AND ((tbleDemographics.DelRegEd) Is Null) AND ((tbleDemographics.DelConsult) Is Null) AND ((tbleDemographics.DelRes) Is Null) AND ((tbleDemographics.DelPara) Is Null) AND ((tbleDemographics.[DelMIPull-out]) Is Null) AND ((tbleDemographics.DelMIInc) Is Null) AND ((tbleDemographics.OTServices) Is Null) AND ((tbleDemographics.PTServices) Is Null) AND ((tbleDemographics.OIServices) Is Null) AND ((tbleDemographics.SpServices) Is Null) AND ((tbleDemographics.Notes) Is Null));
```

That looks too messy for my taste, but I want to simply that if possible so that I don't actually have to qualify each entry.

After looking at it some more, I feel quite silly about the SQL that I did put up here. SO yes, I see that I put the Is Nulls in the wrong place and that the way I have it set up with basically overwrite everything... oops. I hope though that the general idea is understood.

Ok...so now that I am getting more and more into this database trying to figure this out myself... I see so many issues that it is not even funny. This database is set up horribly to the point to where it is a nightmare.... if anyone can still come up with a general idea to what I am getting up that would be greatly Appreciated.

Comment: Database merging = death. You have to deal with key collisions, deletions, and many other nightmares.

Comment: Yeah.. the teachers were supposed to just take care of all of their own data but somehow they got the idea that the person before me was supposed to be their permanent helper.... so... now I have to do it.

Comment: Is there a lot of common data between the databases, or just the structure?

Comment: The data is pretty much the exact same in these tables except for the test scores in these tables.

Comment: Do you have access to any scripting language to interact with this? It would be better to retrieve a list of fields than to populate than to hardcode it as you have there.

Answer (score 1):

Database merging is such a problem that you're probably best off dumping the data out of both databases, merging the data, and then importing it back into a new database. Note that you may need to renumber the keys of any records added to the database, as the keys will collide with entries in the other database. But since it's a database, the keys will also need to be changed in any records that are linked to that one.

If a record is missing in one database but not the other, is it a deletion or an insertion? Or a version problem?

In Access this is particularly difficult as there is no journalling to help you see the history of updates.

Comment: I have moved them to their own little place in case something happens when I am doing this. Basically the situation is that each teacher has half the students. So they only update the test scores for their half. I want to merge them so that they basically have what each other did. The kids themselves are already in each table, just not the scores.